# Appropriate slack for door jambs

Tags: doors, carpentry, door-frame, jamb, shimming

Generally speaking, what's an appropriate gap to leave between the door jamb and the stud?

In my particular situation, neither wall is plumb. On the left, I adjusted for it with some padding that you can see in three places. With that adjustment, the current rough opening is 24 1/8" at the bottom and 25" at the top. What should be the total width (outer-to-outer dimension) of the door jambs. I can afford to make it 24 1/8" wide, but would making it 24", and giving myself and 1/8" gap at the bottom be better?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to have 1/8" to 1/2" gap all round. if you run out of gap you do not need to pack it, you can even plane the back of the jamb to make it fit.